# Wordpress Missed Schedule Cronjob for direct mysql DB UPDATE

Tags: mysql, cron

i can't find a way how to implement those lines here in a cronjob from the original plugins http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/missed-schedule-wordpress-plugin-fix/ or http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-missed-schedule/ it doesn't matter =)

```
function fix_missed_shedule() {
global $table_prefix;   
    $now_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", _NOW_TIME);
    $sql = "SELECT `ID` FROM `".$table_prefix."posts` WHERE `post_date_gmt` <= '".$now_time."' AND `post_status` LIKE 'future' LIMIT 0 , 35";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
wp_publish_post($row['ID']);
    }
}
```

**SUMMARY:**
- the limit of 35 is not necessary
- the connection to the DB is like it's described here `http://www.werockyourweb.com/cron-job-mysql`, each blog gets his DB, USER, IP/HOST, TABLE

I am looking for a answer on this question since 3 days LOL

**SHORT WAY, WHAT I NEED TO IMPLEMENT TO BE RUN IN CRONJOB:**
change the status of a post from table "wp_posts" in "post_date" **"future" to "publish"** if the date is before the current time

UPDATE!!!!!!!!!!!!
I found the answer myself, its:
Ok someone told me the answer, here you go:

```
update database_name.wp_posts set wp_posts.post_status='publish'  where post_date<=now() and post_date_gmt<=now()
```

Comment: Anyone reading this: definitely DO NOT use the query provided at the bottom, this will set all types of posts (including trashed, post revisions, etc) to a normal post.

Use the following:

`UPDATE wp_posts SET wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'  WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'future' AND wp_posts.post_date <= NOW()`